# AWS lambda: check if function run unsuccessfully

Tags: amazon-web-services, error-handling, aws-lambda, workflow

so I know `AWS lambdas` as mostly a stateless thing (though I read some people built stateful-ish things around it ) so this may be an already answered question from the beginning but:

say you want to run a lambda function with an orchestrator of your own (i.e.: `Airflow`) and you want to deploy certain functions with lambda functions and you may continue in the pipeline **ONLY** if the lambda function is successful (I don't mean provision/build/stuff like that , I mean it's got an error inside it that prevents it from running). in order to do so I would have to check whether the function experienced some errors during runtime.

I know there are `AWS step functions` that do this in-house but for a variety of reasons we prefer not to use them. are there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not very clear to me what exactly you need but i would recommend *AWS Step Functions* if you want to coordinate lambdas.

There is also the functionality to invoke a lambda **synchronously** (and wait for the response), or **asynchronously** ([Ref](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_Invoke.html)).

I have done this with Node.js ([Ref](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#invoke-property)):

```
 let params = {
  FunctionName: 'myfunction', /* required */
  InvocationType: Event | RequestResponse | DryRun,
  Payload: Buffer.from('...') || 'STRING_VALUE' /* Strings will be Base-64 encoded on your behalf */
};

await lambda.invoke(params).promise();
```

Comment: basically with our orchestrator we are coordinating across multiple vendors (where different databases are stored) and are a mix of EC2 / eventually cluster on command with a vendor / distributed lambda work such as this case. Synchronous invocation might actually work since the pipelines themselves are called asynchronously!

Comment: Great give it a try , othwerwise Step functions are annoying but the service can do amazing things.